# Choosing Drawable to show on a imageview programmatically

Tags: android, view, imageview

I have say N images that i want to include in my android project resources, say image0 to imageN-1, how do I set an image view to show one of those drawables say imagei when i is known only at runtime?

something like that:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable("R.drawable.image"+i));
```

obviously that wouldnt work but you know what i mean...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Resources.getIdentifier()` as in this blog [explained](http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/)